# is there a way to do something like PQsetSingleRowMode() with the psql client?

Tags: psql

I did a `\?` but I don't see anything to suggest that I can get the client to do this.

I am using version 9.4

```
psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.4.0
```

The idea is that I want to be able to run large queries in the psql client and limit the memory consumption of the client by streaming the results in one at a time from the server vs. getting all the results at once.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Do not post code or additional information in comments